# Is it possible to run WPF triggers on a secondary thread?

Tags: wpf

just wondering is it possible to run WPF triggers on a secondary thread? I have a wpf grid ( Microsoft one) with over 100k rows and the viewport has about 50-70 rows with fast moving streaming data. Scrolling down whilst the data is updating feels fine and snappy but the minute i put some triggers to to highlight cells or rows, it starts to hang up a bit on scroll. Was wondering is it possible to run WPF triggers on a secondary thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether or not this qualifies as an answer but here goes:

Are you absolutely sure a user of the application wants to see 100K rows?

Why not load new rows asynchronously and move out/delete old rows?

You could simulate the vast amount of rows by manipulating a scrollbar and/or paging controls to simulate the actual amount of rows but never load more than a couple of hundred.